# show stars (&#9733) in mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

I what to put some stars ★ (`&#9733;`) in a pdf using MPDF, but it doesnt work

This is the code:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion=true;
$mpdf->charset_in='UTF-8';

$html ="";

ob_start();

$obj = json_decode($myJSON,true);
foreach($obj as $data)
{
    if($data['llave'] == 'Autoritario')
    {
        for($i=0;$i<$data['stars'];$i++)
        { 
            echo "&#9733;"; 
        }
    }
}

$html = ob_get_contents();//get the content
ob_end_clean();//erase the output buffer
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
?>
```

I tried:

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML(utf8_encode($html));
```

and:

```
{ 
    echo utf8_encode("&#9733";)
```

but It, doesn't work,  it shows me:

[image]

Comment: You need to change the default font of MPDF. Use the font that support the star character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced the same problem once. The trick is to change the default font with custom font that supports the character you want to print.

To add custom font to MPDF, Download and copy century-gothic.tff to ttfonts folder inside mpdf folder.
Download Link: https://www.wfonts.com/font/century-gothic

Change the default font in your MPDF configuration.

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
            'mode' => 'utf-8',
            'format' => 'A4',
            'default_font' => 'mycustomfont',
            'margin_left' => 15,
            'margin_right' => 10,
            'margin_top' => 16,
            'margin_bottom' => 10,
            'margin_header' => 10,
            'margin_footer' => 10
    ]);
```

Now, add your custom font to the fontVairables.php
//mpdf/source/config/fontVariables.php

```
"mycustomfont" => [
    'R' => "century-gothic.ttf",
    'B' => "century-gothic-Bold.ttf",                   
 ],
```

Comment: It worked!! thanks!!! I just put the mpdf configuration as you said. and show me the stars. thanks again!